# My iphone app leaks memory, but very slowly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

It leaks about 1/10th of a megabyte every 7 seconds, when the character is moving.  Is this amount of leakage expected?  I can't figure out what's causing the leak, because instruments doesn't pick it up, so I'm wondering if I can just leave it.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to say on the basis of what's been provided so far, but if it doesn't plateau at some point, then clearly you have a problem. And, even if the Leaks tool isn't identifying anything, doesn't mean you don't have a problem.

I'd refer you to WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) which not only walks you through some important considerations, but shows you how to use Instruments to identify issues.

I assume you've also run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu) and you have a clean bill of health there?

Comment: I agree with this.  Leaks may not pick it up as a leak probably because it technically isn't.  Doesn't mean you shouldn't be cleaning up your memory though.  For that, you can use the allocations instrument which you may find in robs link.

Comment: Heapshot analysis is typically very effective at figure out these kinds of issues.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: @bbum Agreed. That video spends a lot of talk illustrating this heapshot analysis technique. Personally, I find option-dragging in the allocations graph timeline (to select a range) is a really quick way of finding theses issues, too.

Comment: @Rob I should probably watch more WWDC videos.